# How load an image when it comes to the div area?

Tags: javascript

I have a div `overflow=hidden;` like the one I add here. I have some image in it, some in the visible div area and some are out of it (meaning if the div width is 300, the image left be 500 so you can't see the image). I change images position (all with each other) with a JavaScript function. **How to load the image just when it comes to the div area (meaning: top and left of image be in div width and height)?**

And I move images with a Generic Drag, like one here described in *[Generic Drag](http://www.brainjar.com/dhtml/drag/default.asp)*.

```
<div id="mydiv" style="overflow=hidden; width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #f00;">
    <img id="Img1" border="0"
         style="z-index: 10; position: absolute; visibility: visible; left: 481px; top: 347px; height: 15px; width: 16px;"
         src="house1.gif">
    <img id="Img2" border="0"
         style="z-index: 10; position: absolute; visibility: visible; left: 200px; top: 200px; height: 15px; width: 16px;"
         src="house1.gif">
    <img id="Img3" border="0"
         style="z-index: 10; position: absolute; visibility: visible; left: -50px; top: -50px; height: 15px; width: 16px;"
         src="house1.gif">
    <img id="Img4" border="0"
         style="z-index: 10; position: absolute; visibility: visible; left: 481px; top: 50px; height: 15px; width: 16px;"
         src="house1.gif">
    <img id="Img5" border="0"
         style="z-index: 10; position: absolute; visibility: visible; left: 50px; top: 60px; height: 15px; width: 16px;"
         src="house1.gif">
</div>
```

Comment: Try to reword your question, it is difficult to understand

Comment: @Ibu  updated, and which part is difficult to understand

Comment: Thank you now it make much more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a position relative to your `div`, and you can track the position of the image position (top/left) and when the image is in range add the `src` property to your img attribute.

I recommend using [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) as it will give you more functionality and more browser support of *[drag and drop](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)*.

Example:

```
<img id="Img1" border="0" style="z-index: 10; position: absolute; visibility: visible;
            left: 481px; top: 347px; height: 15px; width: 16px;" deffered="house1.gif">
```

JavaScript code:

```
// If image is in range.
var image = $('Img1');
image.attr('src',image.attr('deffered'));
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<div id="mydiv" style="overflow:hidden; min-height:300px; min-width:300px;  border: 1px solid #f00;">
      <img id="Img1" border="0" style="z-index: 10; 
            left: 481px; top: 347px; height: 400px; width: 400px;" src="...">
  </div>
```

Comment: The question is to only load the image when it is in the visible range